# Extracting data from one server to other in couchDB

Tags: couchdb

Hello I am new to couchDB. I have around 100 document and also the insertion is very hard to do alone. can any one let me know if there are possible of dividing the document into two computer and then combine into single system. 
The process can be through cable or through wireless.Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use CouchDB's Replicator.
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/replication/replicator.html#basics

You can do it on Futon accessing http://couchdb:5984/_utils/replicator.html

I've been used it everytime when I wish share a database on different environments. Does that help you?

Comment: ya i know that but how do you connect? through cable wire is it? I have this Replicate change from: In that i am selecting Local Database (my name in that) . But in to i have same two option that is local database and remote database can you please help me out in that?

Comment: @AjayKumarHolla you don't need a cable. You can, for instance, open two CouchDB instance in two different tabs in your browser. So, you can log in into both instances. Then you will access replicator, choose a local database and other remote database with its address:

Local Database: **dbA**
Remote Database: http://othercouchdb:5984/dbB

CouchDB will create (if doesnt exist) **dbB** like **dbA** in local database.